# "Connection closed by (ip adress) port 22" when trying to connect to raspberry pi with ssh

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

I am having a problem when trying to connect to my raspberry pi from my ubuntu 18.04 machine. When I type `ssh user@ip_adress` I get this output: `Connection closed by (ip adress) port 22`. SSH is enabled on the raspberry pi. When I am on my raspberry pi, I can connect to the ubuntu machine without any problem.

Any ideas about what might be preventing me from using SSH to connect to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Local network? Or trying to do it over the internet?

Comment: The two systems have two different internet connections, so I guess it might be over the internet.

Comment: Both the main computer and the raspberry are in my house, so maybe it is local network.

Comment: What OS are you running on the Pi?

Comment: On the Raspberry Pi, I am running Ubuntu MATE 18.04.2 LTS Bionic Beaver 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! Here is it, short and simple: 
The only thing I had to do was to run this command on my raspberry pi: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`. After that, it just worked!